# Deadlock acquiring locks

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I've got a thread dump for a deadlock and I can't see the cause. On first inspection it looks like some client code simply fails to acquire the lock on a `ReentrantLock` which is owned by `MyClass`:

```
"qtp1450652220-77" Id=77 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@1e319fef owned by "pool-2-thread-2" Id=1651
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@1e319fef
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireQueued(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:870)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquire(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1199)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync.lock(ReentrantLock.java:209)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock(ReentrantLock.java:285)
    at com.mycode.MyClass.methodName(MyClass.java:1008)
```

However the owning thread's dump is:

```
"pool-2-thread-2" Id=1651 WAITING on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@56171f7a
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    -  waiting on java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject@56171f7a
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Number of locked synchronizers = 1
    - java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync@1e319fef
```

Sure enough the lock on the ReentrantLock is listed at the bottom. But what surprises me is there's none of my client code in the thread dump. There's no indication as to how that ReentrantLock was acquired in the first place, so how can I fix it?

The code in MyClass is:

```
public Collection<String> methodName() {

    interruptLock.lock();
    try {
        /* do stuff */
        return tagsToReturn;
    } finally {
        interruptLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Line 1008 is the `interruptLock.lock();` line.

Comment: interruptLock then is a RentrantLock.  So at the bottom of the stack there is your methods call to java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lock which is the next item on the stack.   My question is what is the context is the other thread from?

Comment: This is what is inexplicable. I don't know and I don't understand how anything could've locked it without passing through client code.

Comment: thread qtp1450652220-77 obviously locked it.   Where is interruptLock defined?  Its not in your method, its in your class.   Where else in the class could interruptLock.lock be called async to your method call.

Its also possible that we are dealing with two separate ReentrantLocks here.

Comment: It's a private member variable of `MyClass`. It can also be called externally via an accessor via a method called `interruptBegin` (with companion `interruptEnd` to unlock). Maybe `pool-2-thread-2` has previously locked it and failed to unlock it...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you have to capture the thread stack with jstack and -l option:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jstack.html

> -l
>
> Long listing. Prints additional information about locks such as a list of owned java.util.concurrent ownable synchronizers. See the
> AbstractOwnableSynchronizer class description at
> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/AbstractOwnableSynchronizer.html